# C# RSA encrypt/decrypt throws exception

Tags: c#, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I'm trying to set up a simple server side RSA encryption of a small chunk of info which is to be decrypted on the client side. Just as a proof of concept I wrote a few lines to ensure that the public and private key could be loaded from xml. However, I'm struggling to make even the most simple stuff work on my machine:

```
  byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Some text");
  bool fOAEP = true;

  // seeding a public and private key
  RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
  var publicKey = rsa.ToXmlString(false);
  var privateKey = rsa.ToXmlString(true);

  //server side
  RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaServer = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
  rsaServer.FromXmlString(privateKey);
  var encrypted = rsaServer.Encrypt(bytes, fOAEP);

  //client side
  RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaClient = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
  rsaClient.FromXmlString(publicKey);
  var decrypted = rsaClient.Decrypt(encrypted, fOAEP);
```

The last call to Decrypt throw a CryptographicException with the message "Error occurred while decoding OAEP padding.". I must be missing something totally obvious here. Do I need more setup of the rsa instances or maybe the initial rsa seeding instance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use public key for encryption and private key for decryption.
Take a look here: [RSACryptoServiceProvider decrypt with public key](http://www.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/microsoft.public.dotnet.security/2004-05/0270.html)

> Now, let's get back to the
>   RSACryptoServiceProvider class. The
>   Encrypt  method ONLY encrypts using
>   the public key and the Decrypt method
>   only  decrypts using the private key.